# First letter of a string to capital

Tags: string, validation, pascal, uppercase

Is there a syntax (like Uppercase(s)) in pascal to convert first letter of a string to an uppercase. First letter only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; you might use `UpCase` function (hope most of Pascal variants have it). Below is shown, how to use it for capitalizing first char in the given `S` string.

```
function UpCaseFirstChar(const S: string): string;
begin
  Result := S;

  if Length(Result) > 0 then
    Result[1] := UpCase(Result[1]);
end;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks I got it working but can you explain to me how the [1] works please? :)

Comment: If `s` is a string, then `s[n]` is the nth letter of `s`.